# C# get username from string. split

Tags: c#, string, split

Hello everybody i want to split text and get value

How i can get `Example` from here:

```
L 02/28/2012 - 04:52:05: "Example<2><VALVE_ID_PENDING><>" entered the game
```

i tried whole bunch of stuff but it was very difficult for me?
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try something like

```
string s = "L 02/28/2012 - 04:52:05: \"Example<2><VALVE_ID_PENDING><>\" entered the game";
int start = s.IndexOf('"')+1;
int end = s.IndexOf('<');
var un = s.Substring(start, end-start);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// say you have your text in the text variable
var yourExtractedText = text.Split('"').Split('<')[0];
```

Careful though, this will cause exceptions if the format of the string changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give character before the start of the output string you do `myString.Split('"');` you will get array of strings which is

```
string[] myStringArray = myString.Split('"');

myStringArray[0]  contains L 02/28/2012 - 04:52:05: 
myStringArray[1]  contains Example<2><VALVE_ID_PENDING><>" 
myStringArray[2]  contains entered the game
```

You can apply this logic and build the required string.

Remember to use StringBuilder while constructing the string again.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using regular expressions to find what you are looking for:

```
Match match = Regex(inputString, "\"([\w\s]+)<");
if (match.Success) {
    String username = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Take care to include the information you know has to be present. For example if you *know* that your username starts with a quotation mark, consists only of word characters and whitespace and ends with a angle-bracket delimited number, you might instead write:

```
Match match = Regex(inputString, "\"([\w\s]+)<[0-9]+>");
if (match.Success) {
    String username = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string temp = GetExample("L 02/28/2012 - 04:52:05: \"Example<2><VALVE_ID_PENDING><>\" entered the game");
        }

    private string GetExample(string text)
    {
        int startIndex = text.IndexOf('"');
        int endIndex = text.IndexOf('<');

        return text.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1);
    }
```

Don't forget that before `"` in a string should come a `\`.